# Getting ChannelID from JSON with GuildID as key

Tags: json, discord.py

I have a bot that creates its own category and channels when setup then it adds all guild ids, channel names, and channel ids to a JSON file. The channel names are always the same but the channel IDs are obviously different for each guild. I'm trying to figure out how to separate my code by each guild + channel ID so only certain commands can be used in that channel. Here is the code I have in my `on_ready`:

```
guilds = client.guilds
    serverids = {}
    for guild in guilds:
        serverids[guild.id] = []
        for channel in guild.channels:
            serverids[guild.id].append({channel.name: channel.id})
    with open("serverids.json", "w") as file:
        json.dump(serverids, file, indent=4)
```

This produces the JSON:

```
{
    "622360932089064244": [
        {
            "Text Channels": 622360932089069570
        },
        {
            "general": 622360932089069571
        },
        {
            "Voice Channels": 622360932089069572
        },
        {
            "General": 622360932089069573
        }
    ],
    "623560598226990000": [
        {
            "Text Channels": 623560598226993157
        },
        {
            "general": 623560598226993159
        },
        {
            "Voice Channels": 623560598818652171
        },
        {
            "General": 623560598818652173
        }
    ]
}
```

The next part of the code is what I've been trying to figure out how to separate my code by channel in `on_message`:

```
guildid = message.guild.id
channelid = message.channel.id
channame = message.channel.name
channameandid = {channame:channelid}

with open("serverids.json") as fp:
        serverids= json.load(fp)
        correctchannel = serverids[str(guildid)][1]

if int(channelid) == correctchannel:
       do code
```

the problem I run into is, not every server will have then `[1]` as the correct channel name/id. Is there a way to directly pull the correct channel ID out of the dict inside of that JSON value? Any direction would be great, I'm sure there is a better way to do this but I am still learning.

Comment: Why do you want the channel information at index 1? This seems like an XY problem. Is your goal to get the first text channel in the server?

Comment: This is just an example. When I setup the bot, it adds the bot channels needed (4 separate channels) and they aren't always in the correct index order I will need them in since every server is setup differently. After playing with it a bit, I realized that all of my channels that I create, are always named the same. So I realized I could loop through a range of numbers until the correct one hits the correct index number that contains the name of the channel I need (IE: 'correctchannel = serverids[str(guildid)][i]['botchan1']', 'correctchannel = serverids[str(guildid)][i]['botchat2']') etc

Comment: Now the only problem I have now, is that my bot uses the "general" channel or lobby channel as well, where everyone mainly chats in for background loops. I'm unsure how to grab that channel.name without calling it through on_message. I'm guessing I will have to create a separate JSON file to store these "lobby" channels and then create a command in on_message to dump them into that JSON file?

Comment: So you want the channel with the name `general`. Then try `discord.utils.find(lambda obj: "general" in obj.keys()], YOURLIST)`, which will get the channels with the name "general", assuming the format in your question.

Comment: @EricJin thats just an example. Let's say the bot is in 3 servers. There's always a "main channel" that people chat in. Each of these are always named differently. One server might name their main channel "general", the next might name it "lobby", and the third names it "chatroom". I mainly use these type of channels for background loops to get people to interact with the bot in the main channels, so it brings them to the bot channels

Comment: Then you'd need to get the name of this main channel somehow, or some other prominent characteristic of it. Is there a settings command, etc.

Answer (score 0):

I found a solution for problem after researching for a while. I'm not sure if it is the most efficient or fastest way to do this, but here it is:

```
 for i in range(20):
            try:
                correctchannel = serverids[str(guildid)][i]['general']
            except KeyError:
                pass
            except IndexError:
                pass
```

This will loop 0-20. If I know a server has more than 20 channels (which I never see usually), I will just up the number of the range. I would love for anyone to chime in since I am just a novice. The only thing I cannot figure out a solution for, is setting the channel id for the "general" channel since each server may have their lobby channel named differently. I guess I could grab the channel id and channel name in `on_message` via command